# How can vanilla essence and vanilla extract be used interchangeably?

Tags: baking, vanilla

[This question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/294/what-is-the-functional-difference-between-imitation-vanilla-and-true-vanilla-extr) has answers which explain the difference between vanilla essence and vanilla extract, and which tell you when you may want one over the other - if I am correct in thinking that "vanilla essence" is the same as "vanilla flavouring"?

My question is - in baking where colour is not an issue, how do I substitute one for the other? For example in a recipe that asked for 1tsp of extract, how much essence would I use in it's place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imitation vanilla extract is meant to be used in place of the real stuff, and most recipes probably assume you're using the fake stuff anyway, so you would use 1 tsp. You only need to adjust the amount if you're using something like twofold (2x) extract.